# Проблема с подключением FTP vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vsftpd

Мне нужно развернуть сервер **LAMP  Ubuntu** 16.04.
Я установил vsftpd и решил поставить ftp-сервер.

Предварительно настроил Firewall: открыл порты 20,21,990,40000:50000.

В файле настроек **vsftpd.conf** установил следующие параметры:

```
    listen=YES

    anonymous_enable=NO

    local_enable=YES

    local_root=/srv/ftp/base

    write_enable=YES

    local_umask=022

    dirmessage_enable=YES

    use_localtime=YES

    xferlog_enable=YES

    connect_from_port_20=YES

    xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

    ascii_upload_enable=YES

    ascii_download_enable=YES

    chroot_local_user=YES

    secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

    pam_service_name=vsftpd

    rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

    #pasv_enable=YES

    #pasv_min_port=40000

    #pasv_max_port=50000

    #pasv_address=
```

Добавил пользователя, установил для него директорию.

Однако при подключении через FileZilla, выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Status: Connecting to ##.###.###.##:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER ####
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Мне нужно добиться того чтобы пользователь "dom" попадал в каталог */srv/ftp/base* и имел права записи.

Перепробовал разные варианты настроек конфига, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Если FTP вам нужен не для того, чтобы раздавать файлы всему миру, то лучше вообще его не использовать. А использовать для этого же ssh/scp.

Answer (score 0):

Выставьте в конфиге параметр:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

И перезапустите сервер.

Comment: Добавил и теперь я получаю: `Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (##,###,###,##,##,###).
Command: LIST
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
` Интересно что в одном случае из 10 я все же захожу. Однако не могу взаимодействовать ни с чем.

Comment: И еще выше мой конфиг такой `ssl_enable=NO`, `rsa_private_key_file` -  закомментирован, `rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem`

Comment: У пользователя то есть права на каталог?

Comment: А стоп. Раскомментируйте строки с pasv и должно заработать. Вот тут такую же ситуацию разбирали: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/vsftpd-error-failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-878838/

Comment: Ну тут дело в том что я софт древний ставлю, а там конфиг такой. Добавил `local_root=/srv/ftp/base` вроде заработало, хотя иногда тупит и не пускает. Без понятия почему.